# Is it possible to see many graphical activity layouts at once by any IDE such as eclipse, android studio, etc?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-studio, eclipse-plugin

My android project has about 200 of activity layout files. (include row layout files of listview)

So I spent many times to find an activity what I need.

Who's know a method to see many activities at once such as pic preview of windows explorer, mac finder or storyboard of Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "Navigation Editor" from Android Studio

Go to **Tool -> Navigation Editor**

Navigation Editor is a tool for graphically creating and viewing the structure and layout of an Android application.

[image]

For more information go here: [Navigation Editor](http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor)

Comment: From link: Navigation Editor isn't available in Android Studio starting from version 2.0. It was an experimental feature and we may re-visit it in the future. Information on this page is left for archive purposes.

Comment: added it back in studio 3.2, it was kinda awesome to know that we already had something like that earlier